# AJAX Post no corre se comunica con el controller correctamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

En mi formulario de recuperar contraseña, estoy intentando hacer un AJAX Post pero este no se comunica con el controlador bien y no corre complete, simplemente se queda pegado en "opcion"

El Ajax hace esto, en vez de opcion dice "rescatar:" asi no mas.

```
cedula: 12313
email: zamopi@tempmailapp.com
movil: 1223
rescatar:
```

Esto es lo que tengo en contenido/contactar.php, la forma se comunica mediante AJAX al controller y luego este al modelo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<!-- Librerias -->
<link href="../img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/icon.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/icon/flaticon.css" />

<!-- Globales -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/apps.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/clients.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<header class="header-basic">
      <div class="header-limiter">
        <img src="../img/logo_white.png" alt="Evolution Energy Studios">
      </div>
</header>

    </head>
    <body>

<center>
  <div class="card login-form" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title text-center">Reiniciar clave</h3>
        <h3 class="card-title text-center">Coloque los datos que se le piden</h3>
        <div class="card-text">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Coloque su cedula: </label>
                    <input type="number" id="cedula" name="cedula" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="1234567">
                </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Coloque su email: </label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="perdimiclave@aaaaaa.com">
                </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Coloque su teléfono : </label>
                    <input type="number" id="movil" name="movil" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="0424-111111">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="rescatar" name="rescatar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Reiniciar</button>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>

<script>
 $("#rescatar").click(function(){
    if(!document.getElementById("email").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de email es requerido", "error");
    if(!document.getElementById("movil").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo del telefono es requerido", "error");
    if(!document.getElementById("cedula").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de la cedula es requerido", "error");

    datos = $("form").serializeArray();
    datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "recuperar" });

    jQuery
.ajax({
        url: "../controllers/usuarioController.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: datos,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
        let success = JSON.parse(data).success;
        let msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
        let result = JSON.parse(data).result;
        if (success) {
            swal("¡Realizado!", "Su clave fue cambiada con exito a evolution123", "success").then((value) => {
                location.href = "login.php";
            });
        } else {
            swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
        }
        });
    });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en controllers/usuarioController.php, solo coloque lo que es mas importante ya que el archivo es extremadamente largo

```
<?php

session_start();

/**

 * 

 */

require_once '../models/usuarioModel.php';  


class usuarioController 

{

    

    function __construct()   

    {

        $opcion = (empty($_POST['opcion'])) ? null : $_POST['opcion'];  

        if($opcion == 'recuperar'){

            foreach ($_POST as $nombre => $valor) {

                $datos[$nombre] = htmlentities($valor);

                $datos[$nombre] = html_entity_decode($datos[$nombre]); 

            }

            self::recuperarclave($datos);

        }

    }

    public function recuperarclave($datos){
        $usuario = new usuarioModel;
        return $usuario->recuperarclave($datos);
    }
```

Esto es lo que tengo en model/UsuarioModel.php, solo coloque lo que es mas importante

```
<?php 


/**

 * 

 */
require_once '../require/timeZone.php'; 

class usuarioModel

{   

public function recuperarclave($datos){
    require '../require/Conexion.php';
    $email = $datos['email'];
    $movil = $datos['movil'];
    $cedula = $datos['cedula'];
    $usuario = md5($email);

    $result = array();
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ec_usuario where `usuario` = $usuario AND `cedula` = $cedula";

    $result = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);// or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if(!$result) {

        return null;

    }

    $result2 = array();

    $clave = "evolution123";
    $clave2 = md5($clave);

    $sql = "
        UPDATE `ec_usuario` SET `password`=$clave2 WHERE `usuario` = '$Usuario AND `cedula` = $cedula';
    ";

    array_push($result2, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql));

}
```

Comment: El ajax, no dice nada, porque ajax es la herramienta que usas para hacer una llamada a tu back y volver sin refrescar toda tu pantalla.. eso que mostras, donde lo ves?

Comment: Lo veo en la consola de comandos, el "cedula: 12313
email: zamopi@tempmailapp.com
movil: 1223
rescatar:"